# chosen search for multiple words

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen ([chosen website](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) and it lets the user search for United States by inputting "United", but If user wants to input "United States", the search doesn't seems to work.

What can I do in order to let user search for multiple words?

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <select data-placeholder="Séléctionnez une installation" id="installationDiffusion" multiple="multiple" name="installationDiffusion" class="chosen">
    <option value="15">Test -&gt; Machine 1</option>
    <option value="16">Test -&gt; Machine 2</option>
    <option value="17">Test -&gt; Machine 3</option>
    <option value="15">Test2 -&gt; Machine 1</option>
    <option value="16">Test2 -&gt; Machine 2</option>
    <option value="17">Test2 -&gt; Machine 3</option>
    </select>

    $$('.chosen').chosen({});
```

Here is the fiddle of this code: [fiddle of issue](http://jsfiddle.net/RA8ej/123/)

Here it is the result I want to have :

```
Search : Machine 1
Result: not found
```

Comment: Any example? In my app the language filter with chosen works without problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

answer is:

```
search_contains: true
```

For instance here

```
$("#mySelector").chosen({ width: "350px", search_contains: true });
```

will search into the whole phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the plugin itself lacks on this problem. It works only with phrases started on the beginning of the value – try on the demo site to search after `and T` – no result ;(

There are some issues like https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2127 or https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/75.

May you can try this open pull request on https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/1483

Sorry.